# How to preserve white space at the start of a line in .Rd documentation?

Tags: r

I need to indent some math stuff in the `\details` section of my .Rd documentation to enhance its readability. I am using `mathjaxr`. Is there any way to indent without installing `roxygen2` or similar?

The math stuff is inline, so simply setting to display using `\mjdeqn` won't solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a reasonable "cheating" work around for indenting the first line using `mathjaxr`, at least for the PDF and HTML output.

We need to do two things:

1. Use the `mathjax`/LaTeX `phantom` command. `phantom` works by making a box of the size necessary to type-set whatever its argument is, but without actually type-setting anything in the box. For my purposes, if I want to indent, say, about 2 characters wide, I would start the line with a `\mjeqn{\phantom{22}}{  }` and following with my actual text, possibly including actual mathy bits. If I want an indent of, say, roughly 4 characters wide, I might use `\mjeqn{\phantom{2222}}{    }`.
2. Because `mathjaxr` has a problem with tacking on unsolicited new lines when starting a line with `mjeqn`, we need to prefix the use of `phantom` in 1 above with an empty bit of something non-`mathjaxr`-ish like `\emph{}`.

Putting it all together, I can indent by about 2 characters using something like this:

```
\emph{}\mjeqn{\phantom{22}}Here beginneth mine indented line…
```

I need to explore whether the `{  }` business actually indents for ASCII output, or whether I might accomplish that using `&nbsp;` or some such.